# How can I get the parameters of a lightgbm Booster model loaded from a model file?

Tags: python, lightgbm

**Is there a way to get the parameter dict of a lightgbm Booster *that is loaded from a model file*?** I have optimized my model and then saved it using this line `model.save_model('lgb-opt.txt')` and then loaded with this one `model = lgb.Booster(model_file='lgb-opt.txt)`. Now, if I try to get `model.params`, it returns me an empty dictionary. However, if I manually set the parameters and train again, `model.params` returns me the right parameter dictionary. So, does the set get lost while saving the model, or there is still a way to obtain it? It would be very time-consuming to optimize again just for the parameter set.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since your tag was lightgbm is suppose that lgb.Booster is supposed to be "lightgbm.Booster"?

Since this class has different parameters you should specifically define, which of them u are using. Try:

`model = lgb.Booster(model_file='lgb-opt.txt')`

Maybe this will help.

Comment: Iwan Sivoronov, yes, sorry, I missed the ```model_file``` part. The line you mentioned is what I actually used.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1364 the feature was actually included, but maybe you should use the parameter "keep_training_booster=True" in the train stage.